# How make request to MirajeJS js only when I need it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mockserver, miragejs

I have a fake server created with mirajeJs. All my requests are trying to contact him, how can I make a request for mirajeJs only in cases when I need it while making the rest of the requests to the real server

Comment: Do you need to access MirageJS and real API at the same time? Otherwise, you can create an environment variable.

Comment: yes I wanna use at the same time miraje js for requests that is not implemented now and my backend, I dont know how env variales can help me, please give advise bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a passthrough:

```js
createServer({
  routes() {
    // Allow unhandled requests on the current domain to pass through
    this.passthrough()
  },
})
```

See [MirageJS Passthrough documentation](https://miragejs.com/docs/getting-started/overview/#passthrough).